# Hybris: What causes several Backoffice Long Operation items, which seems to be causing performance issues?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris: 1905.14

I'm having performance issues on a Hybris instance hosted in CCV2. It is slowing down the storefront and the backoffice. If I go to HAC > Monitoring > Suspend, I see several Backoffice Long Operation items. The thread dump also show several threads related to backoffice.

There are no cronjobs running and the Triggers have been set to active=false. After some time, the server needs to be restarted, since the backoffice no longer loads. Lastly, the server cannot be initialized, since it contains data.

There is minimal configuration in backoffice, just some XML configuration to customize the treeview of different usergroups.

I am not able to replicate the performance issue on my local. Any ideas what may be causing these Backoffice Long Operation items?

[image]

Blocked threads look like this:

```
priority:5 - threadId:0x2095 - nativeId:0x82f - nativeId (decimal):2095 - state:BLOCKED
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
at java.base@11.0.6/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.put(Collections.java:2598)
- waiting to lock java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@1e60f80f
at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.cache.WidgetAsyncWarmUpCache$WarmUpOperation.lambda$execute$0(WidgetAsyncWarmUpCache.java:122)
at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.cache.WidgetAsyncWarmUpCache$WarmUpOperation$$Lambda$1481/0x00000008020d4c40.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.base@11.0.6/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.cache.WidgetAsyncWarmUpCache$WarmUpOperation.execute(WidgetAsyncWarmUpCache.java:122)
at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultWidgetInstanceManager.lambda$prepareLongOperation$2(DefaultWidgetInstanceManager.java:223)
at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultWidgetInstanceManager$$Lambda$1466/0x00000008020d0040.get(Unknown Source)
at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.operations.CockpitNGBackgroundOperation.runInternal(CockpitNGBackgroundOperation.java:125)
at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.operations.CockpitNGBackgroundOperation.run(CockpitNGBackgroundOperation.java:93)
at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.util.BackofficeThreadContextCreator$RunnableWithParentThreadContext.run(BackofficeThreadContextCreator.java:100)
at java.base@11.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.internalRun(RegistrableThread.java:141)
at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:131)
Locked synchronizers: count = 0
```

Thread count from fastthread.io:

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried analyzing a thread dump ? You can generate one from hac -> Monitoring -> Thread Dump. Maybe you can see in the thread dump why are those threads blocked

Comment: @dj_frunza I've updated the question with a sample of a blocked thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE 5/27 15:29: Hybris confirmed it to be a bug in 1905.14: [ECP-5030 WidgetAsyncWarmUpCache causing CPU saturation with certain category structure](https://cxjira.sap.com/browse/ECP-5030). A workaround for CCV2 is in the JIRA tiket:

> 1. Upload attached cockpitframework-19.05.14-RC4.jar to your repository under
>      root/*CUSTOMIZE*/modules/backoffice-framework/backoffice/web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib
> 2. Build
> 3. Deploy

However, we are choosing to use 1905.13 for now.

xxx

As a temporary resolution (which removed the performance issue), we have:

- Downgraded Hybris 1905.14 to 1905.13
- Removed/Disabled the hotfolder extensions

At this time, we can't say if the issue is due to Hybris version or due to hotfolder extension.

We have another server that is running on Hybris 1905.14 with hotfolders enabled, and it doesn't have the "Backoffice Long Operation" issue. So, at this time, we're just waiting for SAP to provide some response (or investigation of the issue).

Comment: @pratikabu Have you tried 1905.16? The problem should be fixed already.

Comment: we monitored CPU utilizations seriously on the production deployment day. So we had to figure out some workaround. But we will consider migrating to new patch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation(**from what I remember my thread dump was identical to yours**) in the past and the problem was caused because of a Variant who had itself as a baseProduct. Because of this when sync or indexing was triggered, a lot of stackoverflow errors appeared since the code was trying to also synch/index the base product who had itself as baseProduct to infinity and beyond.

In order to check whether you have a similar scenario you can run the following flexible search:

```
select {VP:code} from {VariantProduct as VP} where {VP:baseProduct}={VP:pk}
```

PS: I checked and the issue still reproduces(Hybris still lets you create this cyclic dependency) on Hybris 1905.11

Comment: This scenario cannot happen in our case. VariantProductValidateInterceptor will throw an error: Proposed base product GenericVariantProductModel (8796094005249@17) got no variant type - cannot be base product

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. In my case, someone from the client also set the variant type on the Variant Product by mistake and created this cyclic dependency

Comment: Your situation is possible if validation was deactivated during import/creation. Anyway, this is still good information to take note of in the future. Thanks for sharing your experience / ideas. :)